# Creating Dynamic Date Column Headings in Cross Tab for Business Objects

Tags: date, dynamic, business-objects, crosstab

BO Version: 12.1.0 on Infoview,
O/S: W7

I am creating a report in infoview, which is a cross-tab. I have departments on the row side and for the column I want to have all Saturday dates dynamically displayed, and this is dependent on the date prompt values I put in to the report when I run it.

So if I put in for the prompts Dec the 08th 2013 to Jan the 04th 2014 I should see 4 Saturday dates (14th/21st/28th/04th) along the column headers.

I started off using a variable and using the function relativedate, which gave me all the dates I wanted:

```
=RelativeDate(LastDayOfWeek([Query 1].[Episode End Date]);-1)
```

but because I used -1 to get the Saturday date it was giving me the Saturday before the earliest prompt date, so I was getting these dates instead:

(07th/14th/21st/28th/04th)

Is there a way I can get these dates but ignore the previous day (the 7th) before the start prompt date?

I want to have this dynamic so that if I put a date range in it shows me all the saturday dates within that range along the top of the report regardless of the date range period.

Andrew

Comment: Could you not just change the -1 to a 6?

Comment: @Joe that would give me the the range of Saturdays but one week ahead 14th/21st/28th/04th/11th. I now would have to find a way to remove the 11th date?

Comment: Any other ideas on on my initial post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're having trouble is that WebI (being ISO compliant) considers a week to run from Monday to Sunday, but your reporting week ends on Saturday.

So, I would approach it this way:

```
=RelativeDate(
    LastDayOfWeek(
        RelativeDate([Query 1].[Episode End Date];1)
    )
 ;-1)
```

If we evaluate some dates with this logic, we'll see the desired result:

Testing 12/8 (Sunday):

1. Add one day = 12/9
2. Get Last Day Of Week = 12/15
3. Subtract one day = **12/14**

Testing 12/12 (Thursday)

1. Add one day = 12/13
2. Get Last Day Of Week = 12/15
3. Subtract one day = **12/14**

Testing 12/14 (Saturday)

1. Add one day = 12/15
2. Get Last Day Of Week = 12/15
3. Subtract one day = **12/14**

I'm at home and don't have access to WebI right now, so I can't test this myself, but the logic should be sound.

Comment: thanks for that I'll try and incorporate that in to what I am doing and see what results I get.

Comment: Is there any way of doing this so I get more than one date column along the top, currently I only get one using your method? I'm trying to get the Saturday dates in between the date range that the user puts in.

Comment: You should see all Saturdays.  Does data exist in the result for all weeks?

Comment: when I use what I had before, which is =RelativeDate(LastDayOfWeek([Query 1].[Episode End Date]);-1) I get the 21st/28th and the 4th dates for a date range of 22/12/2013 > 04/01/2014, and there is data. With your solution I get only the 28th.

Comment: I created a test report, with a date prompt and my formula. With selected dates of 12/8/13 and 1/4/14, I see headers for 12/14, 12/21, 12/28, and 1/4. With selected dates of 12/22/13 and 1/4/14, I see headers for 12/28 and 1/4. So something else is going on. Do you always see only only column even if you use a much earlier starting date? What do you see if you use the date itself (`[Episode End Date]`) instead?

Comment: If I use End date it gives me every day between the date range I put in. I just noticed in yours that you are using the end date in the code but I was using the prompt date and trying to derive the date from that. Initially my set up was that I needed to use the prompt as a reference date to work from but let me try with the actual end date.

Comment: That would do it.  If you need the columns to reflect all Saturdays between the `prompt` dates, then you'd need a second data provider to produce it.

Comment: Yes it seems to work now. I will test with more dates etc. thanks @Joe